# Plotting a function on a complex plane

Tags: plotting, functions, complex

I am new to Mathematica and I would like to know how to plot a complex function, say $f(z) = \frac{-z}{z^2 - 1}$ for $|z|<1$?

Comment: This question has cropped up on this site a few times before. Take a look at the linked questions listed on this page, on the right of your question, under the "Related" tab.

Comment: Start with something like this and adapt the code `Plot3D[Re[-(a + I*b)/((a + I*b)^2 - 1)], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, a^2 + b^2 < 1]]`

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. Got what I need.